# Mercurial how to ignore subfolder containing files already added to source control

Tags: mercurial

I have a project with following structure

```
project_dir/
  WebContent/
    es5/
    ...
  src/ 
  ...
  .hgignore
```

I'm tring to ignore everithing under `WebContent/es5` directory using following patterns:

```
syntax: glob
WebContent/es5/**
```

or

```
syntax: regexp
^WebContent/es5
```

or

```
syntax: regexp
^WebContent/es5$
```

but *modified files in the folder are still being tracked*. Could anybody please help me with it?

Comment: Try your first glob example again, but without the ** at the end, that should work.

Comment: @Nanhydrin Unfortunately it didn't help me. Files in WebContent/es5/.. are still marked as modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is in the [documentation](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#syntax-for-mercurial-ignore-files) for ignore files:

> The Mercurial system uses a file called .hgignore in the root
>   directory of a repository to control its behavior when it searches for
>   files that it is not currently tracking.

If you've added a file in a subdirectory to the repo (either explicitly or before you added the pattern to the `.hgignore` file) `mercurial` will remember it until you `hg forget` it.

```
% hg init foo

% cd foo

% ls

% mkdir sub

% cat <<EOF > .hgignore
^sub/
EOF

% touch a

% touch sub/b sub/c

% hg st
? .hgignore
? a

% hg add sub/b

% hg st
A sub/b
? .hgignore
? a

% hg forget sub
removing sub/b

% hg st
? .hgignore
? a
```

There's an example given in the [documentation](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#forget) on how to forget all files which are excluded by `.hgignore`:

```
   - forget files that would be excluded by .hgignore:

        hg forget "set:hgignore()"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me to solve the issue. So as a conclusion:
As @Nanhydrin sugested above pattern shoulb be:
syntax: glob
WebContent/es5/
and the rest as described above